# Fast Euler's Phi function and linear congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to solve $5k \equiv 2\mod7$ with Euler's phi function. $5$ and $7$ are relatively prime so we can write:

1. $5^{\phi(7)} \equiv 1\mod7$.
2. Multiply by $5^{-1}$: $5^{\phi(7)-1} \equiv 5^{-1}\mod 7$
3. We know $\phi(7) = 6$ since $\phi(p) = p - 1$ for any prime $p$
4. Thus, we have $5^5 \equiv 5^{-1}\mod7$

To check my solution I compute $5\cdot5^5\mod7$ which is 1. So I see that I have a $5^{-1}$. Now, I can solve the congruence:

1. $5k\cdot5^{-1} \equiv 2\cdot5^{-1}\mod7$
2. $k \equiv 2\cdot5^{-1}\mod7$
3. Substitute $5^5$ for $5^{-1}$: $k \equiv 2\cdot5^5\mod7$

I have a solution, but can I simplify $k$? If I can could someone list a set of values for $k$ (is the solution for $k$ unique)? Also, is there a faster, algorithmic but intuitive way to solve  this congruence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\ mod\ 7\!:\ 5 \equiv -2\ \Rightarrow\ \dfrac{1}{5}\,\equiv\, -\dfrac{1}2\,\equiv\, 3,\ $ since $\rm\:mod\ 2n\!+\!1\!:\,\ 2n\,\equiv\, -1\ \Rightarrow\ n\,\equiv\, -\dfrac{1}2$

**Remark** $\ $ Generally one can employ the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) to efficiently compute modular inverses. The above computation is an optimization for the frequent special case where the modulus is $\equiv \pm1\:$ modulo the number being inverted ($= 2$ above), hence the algorithm terminates in a single step. Euler's phi theorem is not a computationally efficient method to compute inverses for large moduli (but it is useful for *theoretical* purposes, such as deducing the *existence* of inverses for elements coprime to the modulus, as well as for other purposes).

As for uniqueness: if $\rm\ a\,x' \equiv b \equiv a\, x\:$ then multiplying both sides by $\rm\:a^{-1}\:$ yields $\rm\: x'\equiv x.$

**Beware** $\ $ The above use of fractions in modular arithmetic is valid only when the denominator is a unit (invertible); else it is a zero-divisor so the quotient need not be unique, e.g. mod $\rm\:10,\:$ $\rm\:4\,x\equiv 2\:$ has solutions $\rm\:x\equiv 3,8,\:$ so the "fraction" $\rm\:x \equiv 2/4\pmod{10}$ cannot designate a unique solution. Indeed, the solution $\rm\:x\equiv 1/2\equiv 3\pmod 5\:$ requires cancelling $\,2\,$ from the modulus *too*, since $\rm\:10\:|\:4x-2\iff5\:|\:2x-1.\:$

Generally the grade-school rules of fraction arithmetic apply *universally* (i.e. in all rings) where the denominators are units (invertibles). This fundamental property will be clarified conceptually when one learns about the *universal properties* of fractions rings and localizations.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're required explicitly to use Euler's function the above is unduly messy:

$$\frac{1}{5}=5^{-1}=3\pmod 7\Longrightarrow 5k=2\pmod 7\Longrightarrow k=2\cdot 5^{-1}=2\cdot 3=6=-1\pmod 7$$

Comment: I would agree that Euler's function is quite messy but it is very simple to find the solution using information that I know. How do you know that $5^{-1} = 3\mod7$?? I am looking for an algorithmic approach such that I can quickly compute the inverse.

Comment: Simple: what number multiplied by $\,5\,$ equals $\,1\pmod 7\,$?

Comment: I can understand that now, however what do we do when the numbers become difficult to compute in our minds?

Comment: I really don't know, but *it seems to me* that there is no definite way but to apply Euclides algorithm, which can be pretty lengthy: $$7=1\cdot 5 + 2\,\,,\,\,5=2\cdot 2+1\,\,,\,\,2=1\cdot 2\Longrightarrow 1=3\cdot 5+(-2)\cdot 7\Longrightarrow 5\cdot 3 = 1\Longleftrightarrow 5^{-1}=3\pmod 7$$